# Use dynamic value as table name of a table storage in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline that uses copy data activity for copying data from blob storage to table storage. This pipeline runs on a trigger once every day. I have provided a table name in table storage data set as 'Table1'.

[image]

Instead of providing a hard coded table name value (Table1), is it possible to provide a dynamic value as table name in the table storage such that **RUN ID** of pipeline run is used as the table name in the table storage and copy data from blob to that table in table storage?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set  a dynamic value as table name.

For example, you can add parameter to the table storage dataset:

[image]

Then you can set the pipeline parameter to specify the table name:

[image]

[image]

But we can not provide the RUN ID of pipeline run  as the table name in the table storage   and copy data from blob to that table in table storage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Leon. Here is the situation - I have a webjob that needs to start right after ADF pipeline run (that copies latest data from blob to table) is complete so that I can get latest data while starting webjob. My plan was to use pipeline RUN ID as table name and before I start webjob, check latest pipeline RUN ID that is in ‘Succeeded’ state, find out the table with the name that matches this pipeline RUN ID and use the data in that table storage in webjob. Could you please suggest an alternate approach because ADF doesn’t support using RUN ID as table name? Thank you!

Comment: @user3693060 You're welcome, I'm glad my answer helped you. About you another question, I haven't tried that and I'm afraid I can't give you suggestions.

Comment: You may post another question, hope you could get the solution.If my answer is helpful for you, can you  please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if I need to set table name as ‘Table<current-utc-time>‘ (so that each time when I run this pipeline, it will copy data to a new table) what modifications should be made in the settings shown in the images above? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @user3693060u Actually, in the a dynamic value expression, we can build the expression to set the `Table<current-utc-time>`, expression may like: `@concat(pipeline().parameters.tbname,utcnow())`.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to update this expression and remove escape characters from the name? For example, currently table name generated is '3-5-2020'. With this I see error 'table name contains invalid characters. Is there a way remove '-' from the table name using expression so that resulting table name would be '352020'?

Comment: @user3693060 I think you can! please learn from the [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions). Using function combination can help you achieve that.