# Use ADF Pipeline RUN ID as table name

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use ADF pipeline RUN ID as table name. On running the pipeline, I see the following error:

**EDIT**

table name contains invalid characters

[image]

Could you please suggest a workaround on this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Can you demonstrate why you can't use the RunId as a table name? Is it an ADF problem or a SQL Server problem? SQL requires table names with special characters to be enclosed in back quotes (not sure ADF does this) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/table-name-limitations?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056682/use-dynamic-value-adf-pipeline-run-id-as-table-name-of-a-table-storage-in-azur

Comment: Sorry, I misread it as SQL table instead of Storage table. I'm maybe still not following why you can't use it: won't @pipeline().RunId will give you the value?

Comment: Answer in that stack overflow says 'But we can not provide the RUN ID of pipeline run as the table name in the table storage and copy data from blob to that table in table storage."

Comment: I guess I'm just failing to see why that is the case. If you can capture it as a Variable value, then it seems to me you could use it as a DataSet parameter value.

Comment: @JoelCochran Error I'm getting is table name contains invalid characters (updated the question with error details)

Comment: I'm glad you have your problem solved. In the future, try to be more focused on the actual problem, and you'll be more likely to get a better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftstorage) the name has to be alpha and start with a letter so how about this dynamic content:

`tbl@{replace(pipeline().RunId,'-','')}`